# how to set binding stringformat to all DataGridTextColumn controls?

Tags: wpf, string-formatting, datagridtextcolumn

This is one of my DataGridTextColumn controls looks like :

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="contractStartDateColumn" Header="Start Date" Binding="{Binding Path=StartDate, StringFormat={}\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}" />
```

Then how can I set **StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}** to all of DataGridTextColumn controls instead of setting every single one ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create custom binding class that sets `StringFormat` and use it to bind values:

```
public class CustomBinding : Binding
{
    public CustomBinding(string path) : base(path)
    {
        this.StringFormat = @"{0:dd/MM/yyyy}";
    }
}
```

And in XAML:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding TimeList}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{local:CustomBinding StartDate}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: when I try this my column is empty.

Comment: nevermind my namespace was missing from the class. +1  thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can store StringFormat in a constant in .cs file; and in xaml use following

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="contractStartDateColumn" Header="Start Date" Binding="{Binding Path=StartDate, StringFormat={x:static MyNamespace:MyClass.MyDateFormat}}" />
```