# Binding instance as resource

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-3.5

I have a very long and repeating binding expression in xaml. Can I first define it in resource section and then refer to it using DynamicResource or StaticResource? Something like:

```
<SomeControl Visibility="{DynamicResource BindingToParentDataContext}">
```

The binding expression looks like:

```
{Binding Path=DataContext.SomeProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:SomeParentUserControl}}, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}
```

Comment: How about answers from [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8290921/1021555)?

Comment: Thank you for the useful link. But I am not sure if this will help me. I added to the original question what my binding expression look like.

Comment: Like in the mentioned question, you can create custom binding that sets `RelativeSource`, `Mode` and `Conveter` in constructor. It\` pretty straightforward.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I have another question. The RelativeSource class constructor requires ancestorLevel argument. How do I specify to search for all levels like it happens in xaml?

Comment: It looks like `AncestorLevel` is defaulted to -1, but you can\`t set it with value less than 1 yourself. So just use another constructor and set `AncestorType` directly after creating `RelaticeSource`.

Answer (score 2):

What might work is to write a [custom markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254.aspx). [This](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/03/09/creating-a-custom-markup-extension-in-wpf-and-soon-silverlight) should be a good reference.

But besides that, you can't "predefine" markups like that. Depending on your scenario, you might can put some of these into a datatemplate, which you can reuse.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare a `Binding` in a resource dictionary, i doubt that this can be made to work using resources.

Comment: yes, it can work... like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912216/binding-as-a-resource